# Centering a circular reveal animation

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to create a circular reveal animation that starts at the center of a `View` (API 21+). I tried using the averages of `View.getLeft()` and `View.getRight()` for x and `View.getTop()` and `View.getBottom()` for y (which is what the [sample](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal) does, but if my View is offset by `CoordinatorLayout`, the values are wrong. I'm grabbing the values in an `OnPreDrawListener`, so the View has already been measured.

Answer (score 9):

I've found that using `View.getDrawingRect()` does the trick.

```
private Animator createCenteredReveal(View view) {
  // Could optimize by reusing a temporary Rect instead of allocating a new one
  Rect bounds = new Rect();
  view.getDrawingRect(bounds);
  int centerX = bounds.centerX();
  int centerY = bounds.centerY();
  int finalRadius = Math.max(bounds.width(), bounds.height());
  return ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, centerX, centerY, 0f, finalRadius);
}
```